# ProcessBuilder doesn't lauch batch files if application terminates too fast - other tasks are launched correctly

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I am trying to launch a batch file right after my application terminates (auto-update file which will replace old jar with new jar). I decided for this pattern:

```
new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/C "+batch_file.getAbsolutePath()+"").start();
```

Originally I was trying just this:

```
new ProcessBuilder(batch_file.getAbsolutePath()).start();
```

I was hoping use of `cmd` instead of calling file name directly would increase reliability. But both options fail if my program terminates instantly after that. U have to use sleep:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File batch = new File("test_update.bat");
    // It doesn't work without this
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    new ProcessBuilder(batch.getAbsolutePath()).start();
  }
```

Without sleep, I don't see anything happening at all. However the weirdest thing is that other commands do not suffer from this issue:

```
// Will run two instanced of notepad synchronously one after another
new ProcessBuilder(new String[] {"cmd", "/C notepad&&notepad"}).start();
```

I tried to combine it:

```
new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/C notepad \""+batch.getAbsolutePath()+"\"&&"+batch.getAbsolutePath()+"&&notepad").start();
```

This sequence is supposed to open my batch file in notepad (so I can see it exists and isn't malformed), run the batch file and then notepad again. Only first notepad launches, then the `cmd` instance disappears from the task manager.

Can anyone confirm this strange behavior? And more importantly: can you explain it to me and propose a solution?

Sleeping for 1 second after calling `ProcessBuilder` is **not** an ideal solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really a nasty thing. Apparently, Windows does keep track of the output stream for the batch files and closes `cmd.exe` if the stream is closed/unused before starting next command. The workaround I used was to redirect the output stream to a file (it's better to log batch output anyway):

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/K "+batch.getAbsolutePath()+">batchlog.txt");
```